# Import / Export files into a SharePoint Document Library

Tags: support

I have one document library (Not sharepoint library) on **F:\PersonalWork**

I have several folder like WorkDoc, ProposalDoc, etc, which contains .doc , .xls, .pdf, .bmp, .jpeg  etc files.

Now **F:\PersonalWork**, I have to display it as SharePoint Library with physical files in same hierarchy as I have stored in **F:\PersonalWork**

If anyone add/update/delete any file(s) in **F:\PersonalWork** folder then my sharepoint library must be reflected this changes.

Can anyone guide me how can I import a file system folder (And all files and subfolders) into a SharePoint Document Library, and also export a SharePoint Document Library to the file system

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature on a list to open in windows explorer. I believe you could map that as a network drive.

Then you can copy and paste the files, ensure your files follow the naming convention supported by SharePoint.

http://www.accuweaver.com/2012/04/10/how-to-map-a-sharepoint-drive-on-windows-7/